# How to click window on mouseover in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mouseover

I would like to have the mouse auto-select the window as it mouses over. This way the hotkeys deliver to the correct window. `view-container.external-view- 
    container` is a container inside the window that I was trying to click on `mouseover`. Any thoughts how I can do this in plain javascript?

```
document.querySelector('.view-container.external-view- 
container').addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);

function mouseOver() {
    document.querySelector('.view-container.external-view-container').click();
}
```

Comment: If it's a commercial website (not for only personal use) I would suggest not trying to implement unexpected behaviour by doing it on the hover event. Say for example the user has another window in the foreground, hovering the website would force it to focus everytime the user accidentally hovers it.

Comment: This is for a chrome extension for personal use. Several poker tables on a javascript based poker site. Making a hotkey program to help click buttons for me - though I need the window "in-focus" to use the hotkeys and having to click the mouse on the window every time I mouse over defeats the purpose of the hotkeys program.